# jQuery Calculations - How to trigger multiple discount conditions based on totals sent to one quantity field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Issue:
The problem is that when a customer inputs a product quantity say over 10, 50, 100 or 200 the price drop should occur on all of the products - not just the one line where the quantity is set. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/freedawirl/fucd6k64/

Question:
How do I re-wire the form to trigger discount conditions based on the overall quantity field, which gets its value from an individual product quantity field? The trick then would be that for each of the product unit prices, the breakpoints would all get triggered simultaneously as a result of the overall quantity written from (var n15_qty_total_b).

```
// Variables for the Business form

        var n15_qty_1b = $('.n15_qty_1b').val();
        var n15_qty_2b = $('.n15_qty_2b').val();
        var n15_qty_3b = $('.n15_qty_3b').val();
        var n15_qty_4b = $('.n15_qty_4b').val();

        var n15_p_1b_single_price
        var n15_p_2b_single_price
        var n15_p_3b_single_price
        var n15_p_4b_single_price

        var n15_total_price_1b = $('.n15_total_price_1b').val();
        var n15_total_price_2b = $('.n15_total_price_2b').val();
        var n15_total_price_3b = $('.n15_total_price_3b').val();
        var n15_total_price_4b = $('.n15_total_price_4b').val();
        n15_total_price_1b = n15_total_price_1b.replace("$", "");
        n15_total_price_2b = n15_total_price_2b.replace("$", "");
        n15_total_price_3b = n15_total_price_3b.replace("$", "");
        n15_total_price_4b = n15_total_price_4b.replace("$", "");

        var n15_total_price_b
        var n15_qty_total_b
        var n15_subtotal_price_b
        var n15_processing
        var n15_final_price_b


        // Variables for both forms

        var n15_processing = 12.00;
```

//First row Local 31Day Pass

```
        $('.n15_qty_1b').on('change', function() {

            n15_qty_1b = $('.n15_qty_1b').val();

// Setting discount break points

            if (n15_qty_1b < 10 ) {
                n15_p_1b_single_price = 33.00;
            };
            if (n15_qty_1b >= 10 && n15_qty_1b <= 50 ) {
                n15_p_1b_single_price = 29.70;
            };
            if (n15_qty_1b > 50 && n15_qty_1b < 200 ) {
                n15_p_1b_single_price = 28.00;
            };
            if (n15_qty_1b >= 200 ) {
                n15_p_1b_single_price = 26.40;
            };

            $('.n15_single_price_1b').val('$' + n15_p_1b_single_price.toFixed(2));

            n15_total_price_1b = n15_qty_1b * n15_p_1b_single_price;

            ($(this).closest("tr").find('.n15_total_price_1b').val('$' + n15_total_price_1b.toFixed(2)));

            // Code to update the total QTY

            n15_qty_total_b = Number(n15_qty_1b) + Number(n15_qty_2b) + Number(n15_qty_3b) + Number(n15_qty_4b);

            $('.n15_qty_total_b').val(n15_qty_total_b);

            // Getting and Setting the Subtotal Price

            n15_subtotal_price_b = Number(n15_total_price_1b) + Number(n15_total_price_2b) + Number(n15_total_price_3b) + Number(n15_total_price_4b)

            $('.n15_subtotal_price_b').val('$' + n15_subtotal_price_b.toFixed(2))

            // Getting and Setting the GrandTotal Price


            n15_final_price_b = Number(n15_subtotal_price_b) + Number(n15_processing);

            $('.n15_final_price_b').val('$' + n15_final_price_b.toFixed(2));

        });
```

// Second table row Premium 31Day Pass

```
        $('.n15_qty_2b').on('change', function() {

            n15_qty_2b = $('.n15_qty_2b').val();

            // Setting discount break points

            if (n15_qty_2b < 10 ) {
                n15_p_2b_single_price = 49.50;
            };
            if (n15_qty_2b >= 10 && n15_qty_2b <= 50 ) {
                n15_p_2b_single_price = 44.55;
            };
            if (n15_qty_2b > 50 && n15_qty_2b < 200 ) {
                n15_p_2b_single_price = 42.00;
            };
            if (n15_qty_2b >= 200 ) {
                n15_p_2b_single_price = 39.60;
            };

            $('.n15_single_price_2b').val('$' + n15_p_2b_single_price.toFixed(2));

            n15_total_price_2b = n15_qty_2b * n15_p_2b_single_price;

            ($(this).closest("tr").find('.n15_total_price_2b').val('$' + n15_total_price_2b.toFixed(2)));

            // Code to update the total QTY

            n15_qty_total_b = Number(n15_qty_1b) + Number(n15_qty_2b) + Number(n15_qty_3b) + Number(n15_qty_4b);

            $('.n15_qty_total_b').val(n15_qty_total_b);

            // Getting and Setting the Subtotal Price

            n15_subtotal_price_b = Number(n15_total_price_1b) + Number(n15_total_price_2b) + Number(n15_total_price_3b) + Number(n15_total_price_4b)

            $('.n15_subtotal_price_b').val('$' + n15_subtotal_price_b.toFixed(2))

            // Getting and Setting the Total Price

            n15_final_price_b = Number(n15_subtotal_price_b) + Number(n15_processing);

            $('.n15_final_price_b').val('$' + n15_final_price_b.toFixed(2));

        });
```

// Third row Commuter 31Day Pass

```
        $('.n15_qty_3b').on('change', function() {

             n15_qty_3b = $('.n15_qty_3b').val();

            // Setting quantity breakpoints for bulk discount

            if (n15_qty_3b < 10 ) {
                n15_p_3b_single_price = 77.00;
            };
            if (n15_qty_3b >= 10 && n15_qty_3b <= 50 ) {
                n15_p_3b_single_price = 62.00;
            };
            if (n15_qty_3b > 50 && n15_qty_3b < 200 ) {
                n15_p_3b_single_price = 62.00;
            };
            if (n15_qty_3b >= 200 ) {
                n15_p_3b_single_price = 62.00;
            };

            // Set the amount of quantity
            $('.n15_single_price_3b').val('$' + n15_p_3b_single_price.toFixed(2));

            // get the total price for row 3

            n15_total_price_3b = n15_qty_3b * n15_p_3b_single_price;

            // set total price for row 3

            ($(this).closest("tr").find('.n15_total_price_3b').val('$' + n15_total_price_3b.toFixed(2)));

            // Code to update the total QTY

            n15_qty_total_b = Number(n15_qty_1b) + Number(n15_qty_2b) + Number(n15_qty_3b) + Number(n15_qty_4b);

            $('.n15_qty_total_b').val(n15_qty_total_b);

            // Getting and Setting the Subtotal Price

            n15_subtotal_price_b = Number(n15_total_price_1b) + Number(n15_total_price_2b) + Number(n15_total_price_3b) + Number(n15_total_price_4b)

            $('.n15_subtotal_price_b').val('$' + n15_subtotal_price_b.toFixed(2))

            // Getting and Setting the Total Price

            n15_final_price_b = Number(n15_subtotal_price_b) + Number(n15_processing);

            $('.n15_final_price_b').val('$' + n15_final_price_b.toFixed(2));

        });
```

// Fourth row Reduced Fare Pass

```
        $('.n15_qty_4b, .n15_single_price_4b').on('change', function() {

            // Getting the quantity input

            n15_qty_4b = $('.n15_qty_4b').val();

            // Getting the single price input and replacing the $ sign

            n15_p_4b_single_price = $('.n15_single_price_4b').val();
            n15_p_4b_single_price = n15_p_4b_single_price.replace("$", "");

            // Setting the total price

            n15_total_price_4b = n15_qty_4b * n15_p_4b_single_price;

            $('.n15_total_price_4b').val('$' + n15_total_price_4b.toFixed(2));

            // Code to update the total QTY

            n15_qty_total_b = Number(n15_qty_1b) + Number(n15_qty_2b) + Number(n15_qty_3b) + Number(n15_qty_4b);

            $('.n15_qty_total_b').val(n15_qty_total_b);

            // Getting and Setting the Subtotal Price

            n15_subtotal_price_b = Number(n15_total_price_1b) + Number(n15_total_price_2b) + Number(n15_total_price_3b) + Number(n15_total_price_4b)

            $('.n15_subtotal_price_b').val('$' + n15_subtotal_price_b.toFixed(2))

            // Getting and Setting the Total Price

            n15_final_price_b = Number(n15_subtotal_price_b) + Number(n15_processing);

            $('.n15_final_price_b').val('$' + n15_final_price_b.toFixed(2));

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that checks the total quantity and gives a discount based on the appropriate break points. Run the function each time you update the total quantity, so in your case, whenever one of the individual quantities change.

Declare the following function in between the first and second blocks of your code and then call the function in each of your .on('change') listeners before you update the values in html. Obviously you will have to fill out the rest of your breakpoints.

```
var checkTotalQuantity = function(){
  if (n15_qty_total_b > someBreakPoint){
    n15_price_total_b *= 0.85 //15% discount for the total price
  }
}
```

Comment: Brybott,Thanks for your answer. Still having trouble... I updated it and attempted to alert the code provided... can you clarify a bit more? See:http://jsfiddle.net/freedawirl/s9w379aa/